# I cant launch my jupyter lab in my Windows 10 machine. Non Virtual Machine laptop

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Hope anyone can help me figure out how to solve.

Here is the message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\AA\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-lab-script.py", line 9, in 
sys.exit(main())
File "C:\Users\AA\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py", line 270, in launch_instance
return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\AA\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 844, in launch_instance
app.initialize(argv)
File "C:\Users\AA\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in inner
return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\AA\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 1368, in initialize
self.init_webapp()
File "C:\Users\AA\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 1188, in init_webapp
self.http_server.listen(port, self.ip)
File "C:\Users\AA\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\tcpserver.py", line 152, in listen
self.add_sockets(sockets)
File "C:\Users\AA\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\tcpserver.py", line 165, in add_sockets
self._handlers[sock.fileno()] = add_accept_handler(
File "C:\Users\AA\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\netutil.py", line 279, in add_accept_handler
io_loop.add_handler(sock, accept_handler, IOLoop.READ)
File "C:\Users\AA\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 100, in add_handler
self.asyncio_loop.add_reader(fd, self._handle_events, fd, IOLoop.READ)
File "C:\Users\AA\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 501, in add_reader
raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I my opinion there are 2 solutions :

### solution 1 :

try to downgrade you Jupyter lab from anaconda navigator .

### solution 2:

1. open your anaconda navigator .
2. click on jupyter lab setting option and then remove it.
3. open anaconda prompt and type  command `conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab`

> open anaconda command prompt as administrator

Comment: The current juypterlab is version 2.2.6  and i downgraded it 1 level. it works! thank you so much